# pandas copy vs slice view

Tags: pandas, slice, deep-copy

i am fully ware of the pandas dataframe view vs copy issue.

[Pandas dataframe index slice view vs copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

I would think the below code <approach 1> will be "safe" and robust:

```
mydf = mydf[mydf.something == some condition]
mydf['some column'] = something else
```

Note that doing above, I change the parent dataframe all together, not creating a separate view.

<approach 2> I make the explicit .copy() method

```
mydf = mydf[mydf.something == some condition].copy()
mydf['some column'] = something else
```

In fact, I would think the latter will be an unneccessary overhead?

However, occasionally, (not consistently) i will still receive the below warning message, using the first approach (without the .copy())

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

am I missing any subtlety using apporach 1? Or should one **always** for robustness use approach 2?  is the .copy() going to be a meaningful overhead?

Comment: Your question is **exactly** what you linked [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). `copy()` **is** the proper way to handle the situation.

Comment: my question is: 
1/ what is the subtlety missing using mydf = mydf[mydf.something == some condition]; note that it's setting on the same variable here. 
2/ mydf =mydf[mydf.something == some condition].copy() is there any significant overhead? by calling .copy() all the time?
whether that's **exact** is semantics

Comment: 2/ whether `.copy` introduces a significant overhead or not depends much on how big the data is, but generally, copy is very cheap, even if you need to copy gigabytes of data. 1/ AFAICT that's the beauty (or ugliness) of python/numpy/pandas: nobody knows, as mentioned in the pandas documentation.